# I don't understand how to display my calculations

Tags: java

This program lets the user enter a loan amount and loan period in number of years.

The monthly and total payments should be displayed with the interest rate which increments by 1/8. So far, I have gotten far enough to calculate one amount correctly but I don't understand how to display all the results.

I took a picture of the instructions for the problem below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUp2h.jpg

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ComputeLoan

{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Enter number of years
    System.out.print("Enter number of years as an integer: ");
        int numberOfYears = input.nextInt();

    //Enter loan amount
    System.out.print("Enter Loan amount: ");
    double loanAmount = input.nextDouble();

    //Declare interest rate
    double interestRate = 5.000;

    //Obtain monthly interest rate
    double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate / 1200;

    //Calculate payment

    double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate / (1 - 1 /                                                              Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, numberOfYears * 12));

double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * numberOfYears * 12;

    for (double intRate=5.000; intRate <8.000; intRate = intRate + .125);
    {
    double intRate=5.000;
    System.out.println("The InterestRate is " + intRate);
    System.out.println("The monthly payment is $" +
        (int)(monthlyPayment * 100) / 100.0);
    System.out.println("The total payment is $" +
        (int)(totalPayment * 100) / 100.0);


} 
    //Display Results





}
}
```

Comment: What does your code output currently?

Comment: right now it outputs:    The interest rate is: 5.0  The monthly payment is $118.71  The total payment is $11322.74.  All of these are correct but i am trying to display the results for each changing interest rate

Comment: You have an extra semi colon at the end of your for loop: `for (double intRate=5.000; intRate <8.000; intRate = intRate + .125);` Remove it and it should work as you expect. You'll need to move your monthly interestRAte and monthly payment calculations inside the for loop and base them off intRate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello try calculating in for loop like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ComputeLoan

{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Enter number of years
    System.out.print("Enter number of years as an integer: ");
        int numberOfYears = input.nextInt();

    //Enter loan amount
    System.out.print("Enter Loan amount: ");
    double loanAmount = input.nextDouble();


    for (double intRate=5.000; intRate <8.000; intRate = intRate + .125)
    {

    //Obtain monthly interest rate
    double monthlyInterestRate = intRate / 1200;

    //Calculate payment

    double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate / (1 - 1 /                                                              Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, numberOfYears * 12));

double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * numberOfYears * 12;
    System.out.println("The InterestRate is " + intRate);
    System.out.println("The monthly payment is $" +
        (int)(monthlyPayment * 100) / 100.0);
    System.out.println("The total payment is $" +
        (int)(totalPayment * 100) / 100.0);


} 
}
}
```

The output is

```
Enter number of years as an integer: 5
Enter Loan amount: 10000
The InterestRate is 5.0
The monthly payment is $188.71
The total payment is $11322.74
The InterestRate is 5.125
The monthly payment is $189.28
The total payment is $11357.13
The InterestRate is 5.25
The monthly payment is $189.85
The total payment is $11391.59
The InterestRate is 5.375
The monthly payment is $190.43
The total payment is $11426.11
The InterestRate is 5.5
The monthly payment is $191.01
The total payment is $11460.69
The InterestRate is 5.625
The monthly payment is $191.58
The total payment is $11495.34
The InterestRate is 5.75
The monthly payment is $192.16
The total payment is $11530.06
The InterestRate is 5.875
The monthly payment is $192.74
The total payment is $11564.83
The InterestRate is 6.0
The monthly payment is $193.32
The total payment is $11599.68
The InterestRate is 6.125
The monthly payment is $193.9
The total payment is $11634.58
The InterestRate is 6.25
The monthly payment is $194.49
The total payment is $11669.55
The InterestRate is 6.375
The monthly payment is $195.07
The total payment is $11704.59
The InterestRate is 6.5
The monthly payment is $195.66
The total payment is $11739.68
The InterestRate is 6.625
The monthly payment is $196.24
The total payment is $11774.85
The InterestRate is 6.75
The monthly payment is $196.83
The total payment is $11810.07
The InterestRate is 6.875
The monthly payment is $197.42
The total payment is $11845.36
The InterestRate is 7.0
The monthly payment is $198.01
The total payment is $11880.71
The InterestRate is 7.125
The monthly payment is $198.6
The total payment is $11916.13
The InterestRate is 7.25
The monthly payment is $199.19
The total payment is $11951.61
The InterestRate is 7.375
The monthly payment is $199.78
The total payment is $11987.16
The InterestRate is 7.5
The monthly payment is $200.37
The total payment is $12022.76
The InterestRate is 7.625
The monthly payment is $200.97
The total payment is $12058.44
The InterestRate is 7.75
The monthly payment is $201.56
The total payment is $12094.17
The InterestRate is 7.875
The monthly payment is $202.16
The total payment is $12129.97
```

Comment: this helps me display 1 result but i need it to display each result between 5 and 8 with an increment of 1/8. the example is in the link i posted. would i have to make separate loops for each result? the intRate variable is incrementing by 1/8 but it only displays 5 which is the first value.

Comment: Try running this code, I removed unnecessary semicolon, and have run myself, worked for me. Updated the answer with my output

Comment: sorry for answering a bit late, but this does work. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image you linked us to, I'm guessing that you're trying to give each column an equal amount of space. `System.out.printf()` and `String.format()` are the functions you may be interested in.

The code below rounds (up or down as appropriate) the first decimal number to 3 places and the second and third ones to 2 places. Each column contains 20 spaces.

```
    System.out.printf("%20s%20s%20s", 
            "Interest Rate", "Monthly Payment", "Total Payment");
    System.out.printf(%20.3f%20.2f%20.2f,
            intRate, monthlyPayment, totalPayment);
```